# save image order after drag and drop into database mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, html, linq

I have sequence of image which can be drag and drop in ASP.NET MVC. I would like to reorder the image based on the position of the image and save the new sequence to database upon pressing "Save" button.

How could this be done?

Image table column: 
ID 
Location 
Title 
Sequence

Jquery UI is used for the drag and drop functionality

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
  });

 @foreach (var item in Model.Image)
 {
      <ul id="sortable">
        <li><img id="@item.ID" src="@item.Location" alt="@item.Title"></img></li>
      </ul>
 }
```

Comment: You should post form with you table data of form it manualy with js.

Comment: Can you show us some code?  It's hard to give a detailed answer based on a very general description of the problem.

Comment: Have updated the code and descripition of it. Generally i use the jquery sortable ui, and i do not know how to save the sequence back to ms sql server after pressing save button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `toArray` method on click event for your save button.

```
var sortedImageIds = $(".selector").sortable("toArray");
```

You can then use that array and send it to a controller action, where the items will be in the order from the sortable.

[JqueryUI API doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray)

Comment: i will try this and leave a feedback